# Should database connections be opened and closed in every CRUD method?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using GORM ORM for Postgres access in a Go application.
I have got 4 functions, Create, Update, Delete, and Read in a database repository.

In each of these functions, I open a database connection, perform a CRUD operation and then close the connection just after the operation is performed as you will see [here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/91483/when-should-you-close-a-database-connection) and [here](https://tutorialedge.net/golang/golang-orm-tutorial/) and in the code snippet below, using [GORM](https://gorm.io/)

```
func (e *Example) Create(m *model.Example) (*model.Example, error) {
    // open a database session
    dbSession, err := e.OpenDB() //gorm.Open("postgres", connStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Log(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    // close database connection after operation is completed
    defer dbSession.Close()

    // create item
    db := dbSession.Create(m)

    if db.Error != nil {
        return nil, db.Error
    }

    return m, nil
}
```

Is that the correct practice  or should  one database connection be shared  in the whole application and let the ORM handle managing connections? as stated [here](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/1053)?

Comment: No, this is not correct. DB connections are expensive, keep them open and reuse them.

Comment: Condiser following [this tutorial](https://www.vividcortex.com/blog/2013/07/22/a-tutorial-on-how-to-use-gos-databasesql-package/) (or even better—grab their (almost) free e-book). The crux of the `database/sql` modus operandi is that the `sql.DB` type encapsulates _a pool_ of connections, not a single connection. So just use it, concurrently, and it will handle the rest.

Comment: that is a clear explanation. Does calling .Open create a new connection each time or does it take the connection from the pool if the configuration matches? and does calling connection.close() explicitly close the connection or does it release the connection to the pool?    as implemeted in JDBC and ADO.NET here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

Answer (score 8):

You should reuse a DB connection as much as you can. Also gorm has a built-in connection pool, so, you don't need to manage the db handle. Simply share it amongst all goroutines and they can share the handle safely, allocating new connections as needed.

Comment: that is a clear explanation. Does calling .Open create a new connection each time or does it take the connection from the pool if the configuration matches? and does calling connection.close() explicitly close the connection or does it release the connection to the pool?    as implemeted in JDBC and ADO.NET here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

Comment: It's exactly the way it is mentioned in the doc. "Whenever a user calls Open on a connection, the pooler looks for an available connection in the pool. If a pooled connection is available, it returns it to the caller instead of opening a new connection. When the application calls Close on the connection, the pooler returns it to the pooled set of active connections instead of closing it. Once the connection is returned to the pool, it is ready to be reused on the next Open call."